# How do I get an object from a relational database with LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, devexpress

This is my API controller to call a database populate a form. I am calling the receiptOrderHDR table for a particular receipt order. Then I use the VendorNo from that table to get the matching VendorNo from the Vendor table. It should return using DataSourceLoader.Load. I need to pass an IEnumerable to that function. I am unsure what to pass DataSourceLoader from what I have from the tables.

```
        var receipt = db.tblReceiptOrderHdrs.FirstOrDefault(r => r.ReceiptOrderId == receiptOrderID);
        string vendorNo = receipt.VendorNo;
        var vendors = db.vwVendors.FirstOrDefault(v => v.VendorNo == vendorNo);
        return DataSourceLoader.Load(     ), options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault` returns an instance of T. Change the third row to:

```
var vendors = db.vwVendors.Where(v => v.VendorNo == vendorNo);
```

and pass vendors to `DataSourceLoader`.